# "-" does not jump to the first non-blank character in the previous line ("+" neither works)

Tags: vim

I have read in many places that pressing "-" in command mode, places the cursor to the first non-blank character in the previouse line, but it doesn't work for me..

When I press enter it goes to the first non-blank character in the next line correctly, but "+" doesn't do the same job..

Any idea?

Comment: @VaughnCato it moves the status bar upwards. '+' moves the status bar downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is mapped to do something else by a system wide vim config file? What's the behavior with `vim -u /dev/null -U /dev/null`?

Comment: He. My first impulse was to answer "Unlock the friggin CAPS LOCK" :-)

Comment: This is why I think it's a good question. A lot of instructions say this or that key -- in this case the "+" key -- but what do they mean? Do those instructions mean strike the key or combo of keys (like Shift) in such a way that a "+" is printed, or is term the "+" key just a name for the key that happens to be double mapped "+" and "="?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing "-" without pressing and holding Shift caused my gVim's cursor to move to the first non-blank character of the previous line of a document I was editing. Likewise pressing and holding Shift and then pressing "+" caused the cursor to move forward to the beginning first non-blank position of the next line. I believe vim wants you to produce what the key's value,  even if that requires pressing and holding Shift.